# Local MongoDB instance is not getting connected with NestJS app.module

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to use NestJS, where I've a .env file at project root level and I'm using `import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';`. In order to get the data first I'm loading the .env into app module and then adding mongodb and using the ConfigModule to get DB URI from .env file.

So, my app.module looks something like this.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import configuration from '../configs/configuration';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env.dev',
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: config.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'), 
      })
    }),
    UsersModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But, when I'm trying to hit the port It's throwing an error saying u**nable to connect to the database.**

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me where am I making the mistake.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in .env file use DB connection as `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/euphoria-dev` instead of `mongodb://localhost:27017/euphoria-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Check the **MONGODB_URI** once whit **console.log(MONGODB_URI)** to ensure that this string is read from the file **.env** File.

error in connecting to the Mongo database is due to the wrong address, which will probably return **null**.

You can also test from the package **@dotenv** and use: **process.env.MONGODB_URI**

good luck.